# How do I redirect base url to the specific one in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect my home page to `/home`. How can I do this?

```
RewriteRule ^[a-z]{0}$ /home //doesnt work
```

My whole .htaccess:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ ?site=$1
```

Example of what do I need to achieve:

```
blue-world.pl > blue-world.pl/home > blue-world.pl?site=home
blue-world.pl/contact > blue-world.pl?site=contact
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```sh
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
RewriteEngine On

# use ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS="" condition to avoid a redirect loop
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^$ /blue-world.pl/home [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .+ ?site=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Internal Server Error;)

Comment: My .htaccess is exactly what you shared in answer. But the error is: `Not Found

The requested URL /home was not found on this server.`

Comment: no, still the same error: `The requested URL /home was not found on this server.`

Comment: .htaccess is working fine. Now I have the file as it is in question and it works fine, except the one I am asking for. `blue-world.pl` is not rewriting to `?site=home`. This is all I need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229884/discussion-between-anubhava-and-bartlomiej-semanczyk).

Comment: I have updated the 1st rule as you had this .htaccess inside `/blue-world.pl/`

Answer (score 2):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following.
Please do make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(home|.*blue-world\.pl)/?$ ?site=$1 [L]
```

***Explanation:*** Simply checking condition part while rewriting URL(home page) that if uri starts from either with `/` or without then rewrite it to /home. Also I am using `L` flag to stop this rule(rewriting rule) here. If this is the ONLY rule in your .htaccess file then you can change above `L` flag to `END` flag too. One more point, this considers that your home directory/folder is in root, if this is not the case then change from `/home` in above to `home`.

Comment: I have also rule `RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ ?site=$1`, and when i apply yours, then nothing works.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk. IMHO this new rule shouldn't be an issue with existing one. Could you please post sample URL which you are hitting here.

Comment: I updated the question herel;) Thank you for your help.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk, sure, I have edited my code now, could you please do check it once and let me know if this helps you(please do make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs), thank you(once you confirm I will edit my explanation part on same too then).

Comment: Hello, I have tried your solution and I got response like this from browser: `The requested URL /Users/kuna/Sites/blue-world.pl/home was not found on this server.`. I forgot to mention that everything is running on localhost. Does it matter?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk, Hello, so you have hit url like `http://localhost:80/`? Could you please confirm once.

Comment: I hit exactly: `http://localhost/Users/kuna/Sites/blue-world.pl/home`

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk, oh ok, looks like we are not on same page. Let me check few things here with you. My rules are written for handling landing page which is like `http://localhost:80/`(the usual landing page one :) ) so when you are hitting your shown url that will not be handled by this one. Now coming to question: `http://localhost/Users/kuna/Sites/blue-world.pl/home` URL should be rewritten to `?site=$1`(index.php etc)? Also do you want to redirect(change url in browser) too? Request you to kindly provide these details so that I could try to help more here, thank you.

Comment: At least I would like to rewrite `/blue-world.pl` to `?site=home`. If possible, I would like to change also url to `/home` and then shouldn't it redirect automatically to `?site=home`?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk, yeah that we could do easily, But what is complete url, is it `http://localhost:80/home` and `httpp://localhost:80/blue-world.pl` OR you have anything before `home` and `blue-world.pl` too in your URL? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: Complete url ends with: `blue-world.pl/home`. Exactly like this. Nothing more before `home`;) Thank you.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk, ok sure, I have updated Rules now, please do let me know if these help you(please do clear your browser cache before testing your URLs), cheers.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk, I have just tested sample links like `http://localhost:80/test/blue-world.pl/home` AND `http://localhost:80/home/` and its getting served by index.php(in my local's case), lets hope for the best, cheers.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk, ohh, could you please do let me know what sample links are hitting and what error you are seeing please, thank you.

Comment: For your current answer: When I hit `localhost/a.blue-world.pl/` then it does nothing with url, but when I try different submenu then I got error like this: `The requested URL /a.blue-world.pl/about was not found on this server`

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk, sure, I have edited my rules now, kindly do check them once and let me know if this helps you, cheers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229879/discussion-between-bartlomiej-semanczyk-and-ravindersingh13).

Comment: ok, I have written it still doesnt work;(

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk, not sure really this answer has worked fine for me, I would like to request you to check once @ anubhava sir's answer, if that helps you too, if you are seeing any errors with my rules feel free to post them too, cheers.